# Bluetooth collision detection

Tags: bluetooth

As I know Bluetooth masters can be connected up to 7 slaves at once. What happens if there are 8 or 9 slaves trying to connect and send data to the master? Is there any collision algorithm like CDMA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I found my own answer. Pairing bluetooth does not enable other slaves to connect, so no algorithm is required.

Comment: still, collisions do happen and crash software apps and firmware on embedded devices. For instance on ESP32 Mcus